# Index of an array as a alphabet/ word

Tags: shell, scripting, unix, ksh

In ksh shell scripting ,  is there any way to do like :

```
a[daemon1]=1
a[daemon2]=1
a[daemon3]=1
```

I want to set flags on the daemon name, check if the flag is high then perform some actions.
Similar to  awk / perl .

Thanks

Comment: Add a pseudo code please of what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use ksh array ?

```
$ x[a]=1
$ x[b]=ddd
$ echo ${x[*]}
1 ddd
$ echo ${x[a]}
1
```

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/ksh/ch06_03.htm

Comment: because, I am checking if the damons is up then stop that daemon and bring up a flag for that daemon , now when i want to bring up the daemeon i check the flag, to bring that daemon up.Else it will bring up all the daemon running on that machine , it is configured into a file.

Answer (score 1):

Korn shell supports associative arrays:

```
typeset -A foo    # create an associative array
bar=abc
baz=qux
foo[$bar]=def
foo[$baz]=ghi
for index in ${!foo[@]}
do
    echo "Index: $index, Value: ${foo[$index]}"
done
```

Result:

```
Index: abc, Value: def
Index: qux, Value: ghi
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use names like **a_daemon1**?

The standard-compliant code for associative arrays you might look into:

```
varcmd()
{
    eval $(echo $*|tr -d "./;")
}

varcmd test '$'$fn$oldrev
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    varcmd $fn$rev='$'$fn$oldrev
    varcmd unset $fn$oldrev
else
    varcmd $fn$rev=$oldrev
fi
```